# Procedure to find a conserved quantity

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-dynamics

Given a system such as
$$\dot{x}=-kxy$$
$$\dot{y}=kxy-ly$$ 
with $k,l>0$.How do you find the conserved quantity $E(x,y)$ in general?
Secondly , what is the difference between a hamiltonian system and a conserved system?

Comment: You probably mean a conservative system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A conserved quantity $E(x,y)$ requires that $E(x,y)$ is constant on the integral curves. This happens when $E_x \dot x + E_y \dot y =0$. Thus form the differential equation:
$$
\frac{\partial E}{\partial x}(-kxy) + \frac{\partial E}{\partial y}( kxy-ly) = 0
$$
You then need to solve for E, either analytically or using other methods..

A Hamiltonian system is simply one which is governed by Hamilton's equations, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_system).

We don't say that a system is conserved but rather that some property is conserved for a given system. For example the **Hamiltonian function** may be conserved.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What methods can I use to solve for E that do not involve solving a PDE?

Comment: I recommend looking at Mathematica and https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/SolveAPartialDifferentialEquation.html if your institution has the license.  Otherwise I would look at https://alternativeto.net/software/mathematica/ for other software which can solve the PDE

Answer (score 1):

Since the right-hand sides of both equations have the form $y$ times a function of $x$, take $E = y - f(x)$:
$$\frac d {dt} (y - f(x)) =
y (k x (f'(x) + 1) - l) = 0, \\
f(x) = \frac {l \ln x} k - x.$$